ASP.NET Core Razor Pages: Dropdown selection cleared after form submission

I have a Razor Page in ASP.NET Core where I have a dropdown list () populated with usernames. Upon selecting a username, the form is automatically submitted using JavaScript (onchange="this.form.submit()"). However, after the form submission, the selected username is cleared from the dropdown, which is not the intended behavior.
Razor Page (.cshtml):


 <div class="rollname">
     <label class="required">User Name :</label>
     <select id="selectedUser" name="selectedUser" class="form-control-1"
             asp-items='@(new SelectList(Model.Users, "Key", "Value",ViewData["SelectedUserId"]))'
             onchange="this.form.submit()">
         <option value="">--Select--</option>
     </select>


 </div>



Razor page (cshtml.cs)
public class PageNameModel : PageModel
{
    public Dictionary<long, string> Users { get; set; } // Replace with actual data type
    
    public void OnGet()
    {
        // Load users data and set default selected user ID
        ViewData["SelectedUserId"] = "123"; // Replace with your logic to get default selected user ID
    }

    public IActionResult OnPost(long selectedUser)
    {
        // Process form submission
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("selectedUserId", selectedUser.ToString());
        ViewData["SelectedUserId"] = selectedUser.ToString();
        return RedirectToPage();
    }
}

Above is the picture for demonstration for username not getting preselected after submission
Note: There is a dropdown which is not visible in the video due to unknown reason.
How do I make sure that after selecting username dropdown value , it should not get cleared after Redirecting to same page . Is there a better approach towards this ?

You have used the asp-items tag helper, but not asp-for, which would be used for automatically selecting the previous value from the model.

Just send a query param on the redirect and read that from GET.  So return RedirectToPage("/your/relative/pathorURL", new { selectedUserId = selectedUser.ToString() });  You can then bind "selectedUserId" on GET and use the "asp-for" tag in Select element.

Frontend.cshtml


 <select id="selectedCircleUser" name="selectedCircleUser" class="form-control-1"
         asp-items='@(new SelectList(Model.Users, "Key", "Value",ViewData["selectedCircleUser"]))'
         onchange="this.form.submit()">
     <option value=0>--Select--</option>
 </select>



Used ViewData here to get the value and select it if it exists
Backend.cshtml.cs file
  public void OnGet(long? selectedUserId = 0)
  {

      if (selectedUserId != null && selectedUserId != 0)
      {
          //string selectedUserId = HttpContext.Session.GetString("selectedCircleUserId");
          ViewData["selectedCircleUser"] = selectedUserId; // I
         //Code to get the available circle and assigned circle to that user
  }

  public IActionResult OnPost()
  {
      HttpContext.Session.SetString("selectedCircleUserId", selectedCircleUser.ToString());
      return RedirectToPage(new { selectedUserId = selectedCircleUser });
  }

So whenever a page it revisited it the value is 0 then nothing will be displayed on the page . If the user has selected any particular username then through on post we have passed the parameter through which the assign circle and available circle will get fetched and also that username id will be stored in viewdata through which it gets pre selected in front end.

Instead of using ViewData (yuk!), bind values to public properties on your PageModel:
public class PageNameModel : PageModel
{
    public Dictionary<int, string> Users { get; set; } 
    [BindProperty]
    public int SelectedUserId { get; set; } = 123;
    public void OnGet()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Session.TryGetValue("selectedUserId", out string result))
        {
            SelectedUserId = Convert.ToInt32(result);
        }
    }

    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        // Process form submission
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("selectedUserId", SelectedUserId.ToString());

        return RedirectToPage();
    }
}

Then assign the SelectedUserId property to the asp-for attribute on the select tag helper:
 <div class="rollname">
     <label class="required">User Name :</label>
     <select asp-for="SelectedUserId" class="form-control-1"
             asp-items='@(new SelectList(Model.Users, "Key", "Value"))'
             onchange="this.form.submit()">
         <option value="">--Select--</option>
     </select>
 </div>

See more about model binding here: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding

It does not work . After selecting a particular user the page reloads and other operation are performed after which selected username gets removed.

The example I provided stores the selected UserID in session, not the name. If you want to store the name, you need to get it from the dictionary. If you want help with that, perhaps you should post another question.

The selected UserID which is stored in the session , I want that ID to be selected when page loads again .
When that user ID is selected it will automatically show the relevant name of the user since it is stored in KEY , VALUE pairs in dictionary .

@YuvrajJadhav Updated the answer to set the value in OnGet from session if it exists.

Here is the sample code you could try:
Index.cshtml:
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    var selectedUserId = ViewData["SelectedUserId"]?.ToString();
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Assign Circle To User</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        .form-control-1 {
            width: 200px;
            padding: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        .rollname {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .circles {
            display: flex;
            align-items: flex-start;
        }

        .circle-container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .circles select {
            width: 200px;
            height: 150px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        .buttons {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            margin: 0 20px;
        }

            .buttons button {
                width: 120px;
                padding: 5px;
                margin: 5px 0;
                background-color: #4CAF50;
                color: white;
                border: none;
                cursor: pointer;
                font-size: 14px;
            }

                .buttons button:hover {
                    background-color: #45a049;
                }

        .submit-button {
            margin-top: 20px;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: #008CBA;
            color: white;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

            .submit-button:hover {
                background-color: #007BB5;
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="rollname">
        <label class="required">User Name :</label>
        <form method="post" id="userForm">
            <select id="selectedUser" name="selectedUser" class="form-control-1"
                    asp-items='@(new SelectList(Model.Users, "Key", "Value", selectedUserId))'
                    onchange="document.getElementById('userForm').submit()">
                <option value="">--Select--</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
    <form method="post" id="circleForm">
        <div class="circles">
            <div class="circle-container">
                <label>Available Circle:</label>
                <select id="availableCircles" name="availableCircles" multiple>
                    @foreach (var circle in Model.AvailableCircles)
                    {
                        <option value="@circle">@circle</option>
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <button type="button" onclick="assignCircle()">Add</button>
                <button type="button" onclick="assignAllCircles()">Add All</button>
                <button type="button" onclick="removeCircle()">Remove</button>
                <button type="button" onclick="removeAllCircles()">Remove All</button>
            </div>
            <div class="circle-container">
                <label>Assigned Circle:</label>
                <select id="assignedCircles" name="assignedCircles" multiple>
                    @foreach (var circle in Model.AssignedCircles)
                    {
                        <option value="@circle">@circle</option>
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="selectedUserId" name="selectedUserId" value="@selectedUserId" />
        <button type="submit" class="submit-button">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <script>
        function assignCircle() {
            var available = document.getElementById("availableCircles");
            var assigned = document.getElementById("assignedCircles");
            moveSelectedOptions(available, assigned);
        }

        function assignAllCircles() {
            var available = document.getElementById("availableCircles");
            var assigned = document.getElementById("assignedCircles");
            moveAllOptions(available, assigned);
        }

        function removeCircle() {
            var available = document.getElementById("availableCircles");
            var assigned = document.getElementById("assignedCircles");
            moveSelectedOptions(assigned, available);
        }

        function removeAllCircles() {
            var available = document.getElementById("availableCircles");
            var assigned = document.getElementById("assignedCircles");
            moveAllOptions(assigned, available);
        }

        function moveSelectedOptions(from, to) {
            var selectedOptions = Array.from(from.selectedOptions);
            selectedOptions.forEach(option => {
                to.appendChild(option);
            });
        }

        function moveAllOptions(from, to) {
            var options = Array.from(from.options);
            options.forEach(option => {
                to.appendChild(option);
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>

Index.cshtml.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


namespace AssignCircleProject.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public Dictionary<long, string> Users { get; set; }
        public List<string> AvailableCircles { get; set; } = new List<string> { "Maharashtra", "Karnataka", "Andhra Pradesh" };
        public List<string> AssignedCircles { get; set; } = new List<string>();

        public void OnGet()
        {
            Users = GetUsers();
            ViewData["SelectedUserId"] = HttpContext.Session.GetString("selectedUserId") ?? "123";
            if (ViewData["AssignedCircles"] != null)
            {
                AssignedCircles = ((string)ViewData["AssignedCircles"]).Split(',').ToList();
            }
        }

        public IActionResult OnPost(long selectedUser, string[] assignedCircles)
        {
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("selectedUserId", selectedUser.ToString());
            ViewData["SelectedUserId"] = selectedUser.ToString();
            Users = GetUsers();
            AssignedCircles = assignedCircles.ToList();
            ViewData["AssignedCircles"] = string.Join(",", AssignedCircles);
            return Page();
        }

        private Dictionary<long, string> GetUsers()
        {
            return new Dictionary<long, string>
            {
                { 1, "User1" },
                { 2, "User2" },
                { 3, "User3" }
                // Add more users as needed
            };
        }

    }
}


